# How can I supply internet to the ethernet ports in my house?

Tags: ethernet, internet, network

I moved into a new rental about a month ago and had a local company setup our wifi with no problems. We are getting wifi via Google Fiber.

The house has ethernet ports in every room and I would like to use them for my PC and laptop when I'm upstairs, because the wifi signal is weak.

Here are photos of the current setup.

1. Outlet, says "CAT5e":
   [image: Outlet, says "CAT5e"]
2. EERO connected to power and ethernet cord coming out of the wall:
   [image: EERO]
3. Modem, getting internet from fiber optic:
   [image]
4. Messy wires (the modem sits on a rack directly above these wires):
   [image]

I have found a connection between one of the CAT5e ports and the modem (trial and error of plugging the messy wires into the back of the modem and seeing if anything changes on my PC connected to the ethernet port in bedroom). However, when my computer is plugged into that port, it does not receive internet. The UI acknowledges that there is an ethernet connection, but is says there is no internet.

So, is it possible to create an internet connection to these ports? If so, how?

Comment: It usually is just plug and play on a router.  Connect the wire to router and connect PC to port.  You do need the right wire for the port, so connecting PC to bedroom, but you only have bathroom connected won't work.  Also depends if all connectors are done right.

Comment: @crip659 Right. I have located the correct wire (bedroom1port to bedroom1router), but when it is connected it says "No Internet". For some reason the ISP just told me that it is not possible with the GFiber setup and I would need to change to DSL. However, there is a huge language barrier and I have low confidence in that answer...

Comment: Start with - can you get internet to a PC using a patch cord **directly** into the router. If you can't do that on any of the available router ports, you can't do it over cables in the wall, either. If it's some sort of WiFi only setup, then you'd need a "WiFi to wired" device (which are available) though whether there's any point becomes a question at that stage. Also - buy a 6-port surface mount keystone box and deal with those loose jacks...

Comment: The modem has a red cable plugged into it.  Where does that go?  The router has a blue cable plugged into it.  where does that go?  The cable closet has a bundle of blue wires, presumably they go to the rooms.  Is that right?  Four of them have patch cables plugged in (Red, Yellow, Yellow, Blue).  Where do those patch cables go?  You have three pictures of cables and nothing that shows where any cable is connected to anything else.  Makes it hard to give you advice.  Anyway, is the modem (black box) in the same room as the cable closet ?

Comment: The red cable in the modem goes to a jack and the other side of the jack is a blue cable which goes up into the wall with all the other blue cables in that bundle. I assume that is the the same blue cable that is going into the router. Yes, the bundle of blue wires go to the rooms. The modem is on the rack directly above those cables (sorry should've clarified that). @jay613

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about DIY Home Improvement.

Comment: I sorta agree. If the question was how to run Ethernet cables through a house., that would be wiring and on topic. How to connect the cables to a hub and the hub to the WAN (and the green grass grows all around...) and configure it all is a Networking question and there are better places on SE to ask that.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that your ISP is locking the modem to a single device at a time. This is very common, as it stops people from doing all sorts of things that are bad news for ISPs. Since your Eero is already working, it has taken that one slot for itself.

Good news though. If you have one Eero, it is acting as a router or gateway. The Eero supports adding additional units via 'wired backhaul', and also supports having wired devices behind the gateway device. If you have a second cable to your Eero location, you can use that cable to run back to a network switch in your wiring area. Then you can connect all the rest of your Ethernet ports to the switch. This will let you add wired devices or additional Eero wireless nodes throughout your house.

If you don't have a second cable to the Eero location, you can move the existing Eero to the closet, add a network switch to distribute the connection, and just like above add additional Eero devices or wired devices connected to the network switch.

[Diagrams and additional information are available from Eero directly.](https://support.eero.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000830546-Examples-of-common-network-topologies)

And, of course, you can just add another Eero device with a wireless connection. These devices are designed to let you seamlessly extend coverage throughout your house. You will get better performance if you can use the wiring to connect the devices together, but they will work either way.

Comment: Does using the Eero to extend the network with (A) a network switch and wall ports or (B) a separate EERO that can go upstairs effect performance at all? It seems like I should be going directly from the modem and that this extra step will create a delay. Is that true? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I did what you said: moved the Eero into the closet and connected it to a switch. Then I connected the wall ports to the switch and it works. Speed is great, too. Thank you.

Comment: Technically adding a switch adds latency. It is not an amount you will ever notice, and will be challenging to even measure using ordinary software. Effectively you will be getting full wired speed, with the bottlenecks lying elsewhere. Also the company that set up your Eero did kind of a crappy job. It's just messy, and they should have checked coverage throughout the house. I'm glad it's working for you now.